# Velocity.js - Buggy looping animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass, velocity.js

I have been testing a theory design for an animated mouse to indicate that the user of a website can scroll downwards. It's not complicated, and I've come up with a design which should be re-usable...

However for some reason if I try to clone the element and append it, it no longer get animated visually? However if I `$.click()` with jQuery, it fixes after one iteration.

Perhaps this is just a browser render issue? Please let me know if you cannot replicate the problem! Cheers

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xw39e0bs/4/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that velocity calculates the start point based on current CSS values. So if you clone a moving element mid-motion, that will become the new start point. Therefore, one way to fix this is to provide [forcefeeding](http://velocityjs.org/#forcefeeding).

Working example:

```
function mouse(){
    $(".mouse .ball").velocity({
    top: ["45%","25%"] //[TARGET_VAL,START_VAL]
},{
    duration: 800,
  easing: "swing",
}).velocity("reverse",{
    delay: 2000,
  complete: function(){
    mouse();
  }
});
}

mouse();

$("#clone").click(function(){
    $(".mouse").last().clone().appendTo("#mice");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xw39e0bs/5/

Answer (score 0):

[In this version](https://jsfiddle.net/nejm5Lpy/) we're reassigning the selector to bring in the cloned items. All of the clones then animate as expected.

```
complete: function(){
  sel = $(".mouse .ball");
  mouse();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it hasn't made a difference, and this is likely because there's no real difference between putting the selector in a variable (each loop of this function should still re-select every element which matches those class names). However, like my latest version, it does update the DOM (as you can see in this video: https://www.useloom.com/share/59305bcf7600425094a603bfe66143aa ).

Comment: It's a strange one. I've found that it doesn't animate if you clone when the dot is at the resting position, but if you clone when it is at the highest position then it begins to animate.